# Difference between imshow(pic) and imshow(pic,[])

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a very brief question on imshow in matlab.

what is the difference between `imshow(pic)` and `imshow(pic,[])`?
when should I use `imshow(pic,[])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Mathwork's website (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html#btp8vok-1) in the `DisplayRange` section):

> Display range of a grayscale image, specified as a two-element vector [LOW HIGH]. imshow displays the value low (and any value less than low) as black, and the value high (and any value greater than high) as white. Values in between are displayed as intermediate shades of gray, using the default number of gray levels. If you specify an empty matrix ([]), imshow uses [min(I(:)) max(I(:))]; that is, use the minimum value in I as black, and the maximum value as white.

Suppose, you have an image which has the lowest value of 230 and highest value of 255, and if you do `imshow(img)`, it will assume that the lowest of the displayed image is `0` and maximum is `255`, so you end up with an (almost) white image. On the other hand, if you do `imshow(img,[])`, you tell MATLAB adjust the minimum and maximum of the displayed image according to the minimum and maximum values of the image. Therefore, in the above example, calling `imshow(img,[])` is equivalent to calling `imshow(img,[230 255])`. This will enable you to see the intermediate shades of gray.